# Ungroup grouped items

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have web part which displays items from any view. I'm displaying it through:

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
String res = "";
SPView def = list.Views[_ViewName];
res = def.RenderAsHtml();
writer.write(res);
}
```

How can I display ungrouped items if they grouped in view?

This is how it should look:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the view's `Query` property, then remove the `<GroupBy>` element. In most cases you're probably OK doing this with a regular expression

```
SPView def = list.Views[_ViewName];
string query = def.Query;
query = Regex.Replace(query, @"\<GroupBy.+?\</GroupBy\>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
def.Query = query;
string res = def.RenderAsHtml();
writer.Write(res);
```

but in more complicated cases you might need to use a proper XML manipulator.

What I'm unsure of here is whether `RenderAsHtml` requires you to call `Update` on the view in order for the changes to be reflected. Obviously you don't want to do that because it'll affect the view permanently.